# Transforming letters in columns into numbers

Tags: linux, text-processing, programming

I want to transform the letters in two columns into numbers.

In the following example I want to change the letters in column 2 and 3 for numbers, so that `A` is changed to `1`, `B` into `2`, `C` into `3` and `G` into `4`.

The first column may also contain the letters `A`, `B`, `C` and `G`.  These should *not* be changed.

Columns are separated by `/` (`<space><slash><space>`).

```
Id_animal / Column1 / Column2
ID01 / A / B
ID02 / B / A
ID03 / C / A
ID04 / A / G
```

The wanted output is:

```
Id_animal / Column1 / Column2
ID01 / 1 / 2
ID02 / 2 / 1
ID03 / 3 / 1
ID04 / 1 / 4
```

Comment: Another question: How a repeated all line? I need to repeated all lines twice. Thank you. And today I can't to do other question!

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the complete requirement instead of posting follow-up comments. Also, are the blank lines in your input intentional, or just a formatting issue?

Comment: Are there always only A,B,C and G  in your file ? Also, you can definitely post more than one question per day...

Comment: Please take some time to properly format your question, and to provide representative input data. For example, you have rejected a proposed solution because "this case change my animal identification" - where is this "animal identification" and what does it look like?

Comment: I do not know how to improve. I'm sorry.

Comment: @AmandaBotelhoAlvarenga: How to improve? This is a platform for questions and answers. However, you are not asking any questions. I checked twice, there is no sentence ending with a `?` in your post ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cut the columns into two sets, one with the first column and the other one with column two and three.
2. Transliterate the characters into digits in the second of these sets.
3. Paste everything together again.

On the command line:

```
$ cat data
Id_animal / Column1 / Column2
ID01 / A / B
ID02 / B / A
ID03 / C / A
ID04 / A / G
ABCG / G / G

$ paste -d '/' <(cut -d '/' -f 1 data) <(cut -d '/' -f 2,3 data | tr 'ABCG' '1234')
Id_animal / 3olumn1 / 3olumn2
ID01 / 1 / 2
ID02 / 2 / 1
ID03 / 3 / 1
ID04 / 1 / 4
ABCG / 4 / 4
```

You get bonus digits in the header... :-)

Comment: `cut -d / -f 2,3 data | sed 1d ...` or `cut -d / -f 2,3 data | tail -n +2 ...` to not translate the header; add in a preceding `head -n 1 data` to put it back

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you only want to translate A, B, C, and G to 1, 2, 3, and 4, and that the first column never contains those letters, you could simplify bgStack15's answer to just:

```
tr 'ABCG' '1234' < input > output
```

Comment: I can to specify the column? Because in this case change my animal identification.

Comment: You should [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/295845/edit) your post to clarify what exactly you want to have happen. Which columns and which letters to change to which numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the variables as desired. Save this to a file, for example `/home/Amanda/script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
infile=~/input.txt
outfile=~/output.txt
while read one two; do
   printf "%s %s\n" "${one}" "$( echo "${two}" | tr 'ABCG' '1234' )"
done < ${infile} > ${outfile}
```

Be sure to make the script executable: `chmod +x /home/Amanda/script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

With `perl` you can apply trasnliterations to specific input colums using a `map` e.g.

```
perl -F"/" -alne 'print join "/", @F[0], map { tr/ABCG/1234/; $_ } @F[1,2]' input
```

For example, given input

```
Id_animal / Column1 / Column2
ID01 / A / B
ID02 / B / A
AG02 / B / A
ID03 / C / A
ID04 / A / G
```

then

```
$ perl -F"/" -alne 'print $. == 1? $_ : join "/", @F[0], map { tr/ABCG/1234/; $_ } @F[1,2]' input
Id_animal / Column1 / Column2
ID01 / 1 / 2
ID02 / 2 / 1
AG02 / 2 / 1
ID03 / 3 / 1
ID04 / 1 / 4
```